# When I use Flutter Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil , How to listen for jumps？

Tags: flutter, navigator

**strong text**
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/tabs", (Route route) => false);

Comment: you can add `NavigatorObserver` in the `MaterialApp` widget to listen for the navigations

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove all the previous pages navigated from the stack you should use this

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/tabs", (Route route) => route.isFirst);
```

Or if you want to pop to a specific page

```
Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/tabs", (Route route) => route.settings.name == 'homePage'); //replace with where you want to pop to
```

Then the newly pushed page will become the first page in navigation stack